# Shortcut to save screenshot both to desktop and clipboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

The screenshot shortcuts save either to the desktop *or* to the clipboard, but not to both at once. Is it possible to copy to clipboard, and to save in desktop, the same screenshot preferred in a single shortcut?

If a single shortcut is not available, the only way is to save to desktop and then copy the saved image to clipboard manually?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to write an Automator script to copy the image to the clipboard (for instance "if new image found in folder"). [A example of that can be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812566/automator-workflow-for-copying-screenshots-to-clipboard)